# C# PowerShell module converting PSObject to C# Class

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing my first PS Module in C# over the past few days and this is extremely new to me. I had some trouble coming up with this to be honest (maybe not enough caffeine) but I've come to a solution now however I'm hoping someone may have some more elegant ideas?

i'm finding some of the documentation regarding powershell to be a little vague, at least with regard to creating modules in C#. Embedding C# in PowerShell, no problem, running powershell code within C#, also tons of information, but information on writing PS modules in C# seems scarce, or I'm looking in the wrong places?

Enough chatter, here's my situation. First, I have a quick and dirty new and get cmdlet sample below.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "TestItem")]
[OutputType(typeof(TestItem))]
public class NewItem : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public string FriendlyName
    {
        get { return friendlyname; }
        set { friendlyname = value; }
    }
    private string friendlyname;

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private int id;

    private TestItem item;

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        item = new TestItem();
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        item.Name = name;
        item.FriendlyName = friendlyname;
        item.ID = id;
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject(item);
    }
}

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "TestItem")]
[OutputType(typeof(TestItem))]
public class GetItem : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public string[] FriendlyName
    {
        get { return friendlyname; }
        set { friendlyname = value; }
    }
    private string[] friendlyname;

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    public List<TestItem> Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public PSObject InputObject
    {
        set { inputObject = value; }
        get { return inputObject; }
    }
    private PSObject inputObject;

    private List<TestItem> item;

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        item = new List<TestItem>();
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteVerbose("processing pipline");

        if (inputObject != null)
        {
            WriteObject(inputObject.ToClassObject<TestItem>());
        }
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject(item);
    }
}
```

Then I have my quick and dirty sample Object class

```
public class TestItem
{
    public TestItem()
    { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And now this is where I'm looking for feedback. From the above we can see that the new-item creates an item, and when passed to get-item via the pipeline it's passed as a PSObject. My goal is to turn it back into the class object it started as, but I need to be able to handle Class/type dynamically as I intend to use this as a helper for a project I'm working on. I'm really just looking for feedback as I feel like there's a more elegant solution here?

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static T ToClassObject<T>(this PSObject pso) where T : class, new()
        {
            try
            {
                T obj = new T();
                foreach (PSPropertyInfo psPropertyInfo in pso.Properties)
                {
                    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (psPropertyInfo.Name == prop.Name)
                            {
                                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                                propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(psPropertyInfo.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                }

                return obj;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wondering what is the purpose of writing ps cmdlet in c#?

Comment: We looking to bundle this in a proprietary application as a means of allowing some automation of certain tasks that can only be done in a web UI that doesn't offer much in the way of bulk operations.

Comment: OK. Is there any reason not to use cmdlets written in powershell btw?

Answer (score 0):

OK, what you are working on is called binary modules / binary cmdlets, that probably a word for googling (it gets me a good number of articles about that). You can also find a bunch of real life examples on Powershell Core github, for example [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility).
From the other side it doesn't seem to be a very common way of creating cmdlets for powershell though, and in my opinion are much more complicated than pure PS code.

Regarding to your question, as I understand your Get-Item cmdlet is getting PSObject from the pipeline, and you need to convert it to custom type using input property names. If so you probably can use ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName property instead of ToClassObject. I'm not any kind of expert in C# or binary module writing, so I'll give my example in pure PS, I hope it's not a huge problem to convert it to C#

```
function Get-Column { [CmdletBinding()]param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$columnName,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$type
    )

    Process { Write-Output (New-Object System.Data.DataColumn @($columnName, $type))}
}

$ObjectList = @(
    New-Object psobject -Property @{columnName="FirstName"; type="String"}
    New-Object psobject -Property @{columnName="LastName"; type="String"}
    New-Object psobject -Property @{columnName="Age"; type="Int32"}
)

$ObjectList | Get-Column | Format-Table
```

So that cmdlet collects parameter values from input object and pass it to your custom class constructor. Also, I don't really need Begin and End blocks, probably those are redundant in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mike Twc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624847/7163041) says, you are creating binary cmdlets. They are less frequently used and I, personally, think it is a shame because I see so many "PowerShell" scripts that look like C#, and binary cmdlets allow for native, more strongly-typed use in other C# applications. So kudoos for trying.

I think your major problem is what type you are specifying where. For elegance, you really don't need to be so verbose in the way you write your properties.

So here is a more elegant re-write that should solve your issue:

```cs
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "TestItem")]
[OutputType(typeof(TestItem))]
public class NewItem : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var item = new TestItem();
        item.Name = Name;
        item.FriendlyName = Friendlyname;
        item.ID = ID;
        WriteObject(item);
    }
}

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "TestItem")]
[OutputType(typeof(TestItem))]
public class GetItem : Cmdlet
{
    // what is the point of this parameter since it is never used?
    // Is it supposed to filter? If so, I would suggest using
    // `Where-Object FriendlyName -In "MyName1","MyName2","MyName3"`
    // instead of trying to write your own...
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public string[] FriendlyName { get; set; }

    // This parameter is unused and, likely, is what you
    // intend for the InputObject parameter
    //[Parameter(Position = 1)]
    //public List<TestItem> Item { get; set; }

    // Whatever this type is, because it is ValueFromPipeline,
    // is what the pipeline input will be converted to
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public TestItem InputObject { get; set; }

    private List<TestItem> items;

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        items = new List<TestItem>();
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteVerbose("processing pipline");

        if (InputObject != null)
        {
            // do you actually mean `items.add(InputObject);`?
            WriteObject(InputObject);
        }
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        // this is empty because it never has elements added?
        WriteObject(items, enumerateCollection: false);
    }
}
```

Now another comment: The `Get-` verb, and you can see this in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.1), should act similarly to the `New-` verb in that it gets the instances *already* in the system, but is different in that it does not instantiate new instances. I am not fully sure what you are trying to do, since you seem to hand off the input object to later in the pipeline, which it otherwise would already be going to without the cmdlet--unless you are doing what my comments suggest and gathering them all into a list, and outputing the list

Comment: To note: [Mike Twc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624847/7163041)'s answer with the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` would be a good one in other circumstances, but I ultimately don't think it is what you are looking for.